# Caching current user data in a session-scoped variable

Tags: java, spring, session-scope

How can I cache a current User instance for the duration of an entire user session, so that my services can access it freely without having to go to the user access services and then fetch the user data from the database over and over again.

I know that Spring supports the concept of scoped beans (per session, per request, etc), but honestly speaking, I have never actually used it, so I would be very thankful if someone could show me the way.

I am highly hopeful that this sort of session scoping is thread safe.

Comment: if you're using hibernate you may be better off using a 2nd-level cache for this kind of thing. that way the caching stays separate from the application logic.

Answer (score 2):

Spring is not the solution for everything. [HttpSession](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Session-Tracking.html) is what you need. And [session scoping is not thread-safe](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=140).

Comment: Spring [*does*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments) fasciliate retrieving the session in Spring Controllers, and also support the [`@SessionAttributes`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html)

Comment: Oh, yeah, this is actually not a bad idea.

Comment: you can put a `SynchronizedMap` as session attribute to make the datastructure thread safe

Comment: @JohanSjöberg I know spring provides that mechanism but the OP should first start with the basics.

Comment: @Johan hmm ... this is all nice, but I'd like to abstract my services from the notion of the session. I don't want them to know how this currentUser property got initialized with a value.

Comment: @Pangea, valid point, although I argue that taking advantage of the tools already in place by Spring is a good thing.

Comment: @user802232, you *still* do. Your controllers are *not* your service.

Comment: @Johan Every service of mine is more or less a scoped singleton. Thus, I realized that I cannot simply keep the current user as a property, unless I mark it as per-thread, or whatever it was called. On the other hand, I don't want the services to know anything about the http session.

Comment: @Johan yeah, but how do I inform the service about the current user from the controller? Do I have to add an additional parameter to every method, so that I can pass it on when calling the service? This is a bit tedious.

Comment: @user802232, you do it exactly the same you would if you used `HttpSession` directly. If a method expects a value, then the method should get that value.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring Security, then you may consider to use an enhanced UsersDetails object.

-- You only (because you only know your usecases) have to decide if this is usefull.

---

To answer your Question about Session Scoped Spring Objects:

See [Spring Reference Chapter 3.11.4.4 Specifying bean scope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-specifying-bean-scope) for an example, and Chapter 3.4. Bean scopes for an overview of scopes (*attention the link to Session within that chapter is wrong*).

And notice that Spring Session Scoped Beans requires that listener:

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

*IHO: It depends on what you will do with that session scoped data, whether you should use Spring Session Beans or the HTTP Session directly. For example if you need that data in different places within the service layer, then the HTTP Session may be a not so good solution.*